# Android: Odd NameNotFoundException after application exit

Tags: android, exception

After I installed ADT r22, I get this exception in LogCat every time I close my application:

```
E/LuckyLauncherView(227): in setViewEveryArea()
E/LuckyLauncherView(227): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.doptrixevo/com.doptrixevo.menu.WelcomeScreen}
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:222)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:612)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at com.android.launcher2.lucky.LuckyLauncherView.setViewEveryArea(LuckyLauncherView.java:932)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at com.android.launcher2.lucky.LuckyLauncherView.updateView(LuckyLauncherView.java:513)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at com.android.launcher2.lucky.LuckyLauncherView$7.handleMessage(LuckyLauncherView.java:1429)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
E/LuckyLauncherView(227):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The strange thing about this error is that it refers to **com.doptrixevo** while the application I'm running is **com.doptrix**
com.doptrixevo is my another app, which is not installed on this device. There are no references to com.doptrixevo in this project or in any libraries used. I even tried searching for the word "doptrixevo" in the project folder and didn't find anything.
I tried cleaning, re-creating project - this doesn't help.
My app works fine, but this error worries me. Where does it come from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you previously installed the **com.doptrixevo** app on this device, and then removed it? It looks as if whichever launcher you are using is expecting to find the app (a shortcut or a widget) when it's redrawing the home screen, and is surprised to find that it's no longer there.

If this is a third-party launcher, you may want to file a bug report.

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot! There is a quick-launch widget on the home screen, doptrixevo was added to it in the past and I completely forgot about this. Thanks, you saved me a lot of time and worry! :)